# How can I run an exclusive search on multiple terms in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a company table following Company Names.

- Bill Insurance
- Larry Insurance
- Bill Lark Larry
- Lark Insurance
- Bill Lark

I want to make a query that, given a temp table or CTE of search term strings (I have that part down), performs an EXCLUSIVE search on all of those strings.

For example, suppose I have a CTE/Temp Table containing two records, "Bill, Lark".

I should only get "Bill Lark Larry" and "Bill Lark" as it is the only one that has BOTH of those terms.

I don't want to use a while loop or a cursor.

How can I do this?

I've heard PostGreSQL has a "LIKE ANY" and a "LIKE ALL", the latter of which would be perfect if there was some equivalent in SQL Server.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM [Company] WHERE [CompanyName] LIKE ALL (Select * FROM Search_CTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
select t1.Id
from [Company] t1 join Search_CTE t2 on t1.CompanyName like '%' + t2.SearchTerm + '%'
group by t1.Id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from Search_CTE)
```